# How can I visualize a Graph in (interactive) 3D with Python?

Tags: python, graph, visualization, vtk, graph-visualization

I have a Graph in Python like this one:

```
# Each element is a tuple with coordinates (x,y,z). 
# The index is the id of the vertex
vertexList = [(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(0,1,0), 
               (0,0,1),(1,0,1),(1,1,1),(0,1,1)]

# Each element is a tuple with the vertex-ids and a weight (vertexId1, vertexId2, weight)
edgeList = [(0,1,1), (1,2,1), (2,3,1), (3,0,1),
               (0,4,1), 
               (4,5,1), (5,6,1), (6,7,1), (7,4,1)]
graph = (vertexList, edgeList)
```

This is a small example. The application I wrote uses graphs with about 100 vertexes and 300 edges.

I would like to visualize this with python, preferably with a library which is available for Ubuntu. It would be great if it were possible to move the graph in the 3D-visualisation.

**What I've done so far**

At the moment I use [UBIGRAPH](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/content/Docs/index.html). The visualization and interaction is very good, but I can't specify coordinates for the vertexes:

```
def visulizeGraph(Graph):
    vertexList, edgeList = Graph
    server_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:20738/RPC2'
    server = xmlrpclib.Server(server_url)
    G = server.ubigraph;

    G.clear()
    for identifier, vertex in enumerate(vertexList):
        G.new_vertex_w_id(identifier)
    for vertex1, vertex2, weight in edgeList:
        x1, y1, z1 = vertexList[vertex1]
        x2, y2, z2 = vertexList[vertex2]

        G.new_edge(vertex1, vertex2)
```

**matplot**

I've found [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/index.html), but its very big. I didn't find an example which does what I like, but I might have missed it. Its available for Ubuntu.

**vtk**

The same problem as with matplot. If you could give me some working examples it might be the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

When you looked at matplotlib, did you see mplot3d? This may be what you require.

[MPlot3D](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#scatter-plots)

If not, I'm sorry I probably can't help any more than that.

Answer (score 2):

I've not used this myself yet (beyond running example scripts) but [mayavi2](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/) looks promising. It comes bundled with the enthought python distribution.

Also, a little of topic as it's not in your question, but [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) is pretty nice if your working with graphs in python.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I can't help but think that the name "Mayavi" could potentially be challenged as trademark infringement, what with the Maya 3D software package. Or is it significantly different enough for that to not be a problem?